# How to use broom::tidy for Tobit models?

Tags: r, tidymodels, broom

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am struggling with using the tidy function from the `broom` package. I need this function in the context of a multiple imputation.

You can see here a reprex example using a ggplot2 dataset.

```
library(ggplot2, quietly = T)
library(AER, quietly = T)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
library(broom, quietly = T)
library(tidyverse, quietly = T)

data <- ggplot2::diamonds

data
#> # A tibble: 53,940 × 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#>  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#>  5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#>  7  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#>  8  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#>  9  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#> 10  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
#> # ℹ 53,930 more rows

fit <- AER::tobit(
  formula = price ~ z,
  left = 500,
  right = 1500,
  data = data
)

fit %>%  summary(tidy)
#> Error in if (correlation) cov2cor(vcov.) else NULL: argument is not interpretable as logical
Created on 2023-07-26 with reprex v2.0.2
```

I checked my R version and the package version:

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

other attached packages:
[1] reprex_2.0.2    broom_1.0.5     AER_1.2-10

I identified the following issue and resolution on GitHub but I was not able to transfer it into my in-working project:
https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/749
https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/commit/56437bce30841211bfa64074677fe2d9124d99cc

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a workaround, which you should use with caution: `class(fit)` is `c("tobit", "survreg")`, and there *is* a tidy method for `survreg` objects (see `methods("tidy")`), but `tidy(fit)` returns

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class tobit

So:

```r
tidy.tobit <- function(x, ...) {
   class(x) <- "survreg"
   tidy(x, ...)
}
 
tidy(fit)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept) -3109.    19.7         -158.       0
2 z            1420.     6.75         210.       0
3 Log(scale)      5.63   0.00551     1021.       0
```

This appears to match the results of `summary()`:

```r
summary(fit)

Call:
AER::tobit(formula = price ~ z, left = 500, right = 1500, data = data)

Observations:
         Total  Left-censored     Uncensored Right-censored 
         53940           1749          18261          33930 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.109e+03  1.970e+01  -157.8   <2e-16 ***
z            1.420e+03  6.751e+00   210.3   <2e-16 ***
Log(scale)   5.626e+00  5.511e-03  1020.9   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Scale: 277.6 

Gaussian distribution
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 8 
Log-likelihood: -1.35e+05 on 3 Df
Wald-statistic: 4.423e+04 on 1 Df, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

**Note**: to make this work in `mice` you have to explicitly override the version in `broom` via

```r
assignInNamespace("tidy.tobit",tidy.tobit,ns="broom")
```

before you run `pool()`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Now I try to implement it in a multiple imputation framework, using the same example, and the following lines:

`data <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))`;
`data.imp <- mice(data = data, m = 2, maxit = 10, seed = 1234, print = F)`;
`fit.tobit.imp <- with(data.imp, AER::tobit(price ~ z, left = 500, right = 1500))`;
`pool(fit.tobit.imp)`;
`#> Error: No tidy method for objects of class tobit`

Any thoughts on how to avoid that in such a context?

Comment: `mice` is taking an awfully long time to run on my system - is that expected?

Comment: It is probably due to the number of variables in the dataset, what about trying this `data <- data |> dplyr::select(price, z)` before running the mice function? I tried on my side and it drastically reduced the time needed to run the function.

Comment: I cut the number of rows down to 500 and that made it quick enough that I could diagnose the problem (see my edits above).

Answer (score 1):

`fit %>% summary(tidy)` won't work as the correct grammar is `fit %>% summary %>% tidy`. However, there's no applicable tidy-method for a tobit summary, unfortunately.

Anyhow, {broom} offers you a `glance` at your model:

```
> glance(fit) ## or: fit |> glance()
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 9
   iter    df statistic   logLik     AIC     BIC df.residual  nobs p.value
  <int> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <int> <int>   <dbl>
1     8     3    72669. -135047. 270099. 270126.       53937 53940       0
```

... or an `augment`ed (with model predictions) dataframe:

```
fit |> augment(data)
```

```
# A tibble: 53,940 x 12
   carat cut    color clarity depth table price     x     y     z .fitted .resid
   <dbl> <ord>  <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0.23 Ideal  E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43    341.  159. 
 2  0.21 Premi~ E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31    170.  330.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

You say that there is currently no applicable method for a Tobit summary. Then, do you think the content of the following vignette is not updated? https://broom.tidymodels.org/articles/available-methods.html

Comment: Just checked `broom:::tidy.tobit` of the latest {broom} release 1.0.5.9000 (github install). The method's there (showing that class tobit is acknowledged) but only returns an error "No tidy method for class tobit". So the vignette seems out of sync re. tobit.